# How to update the SQLDataSource of a DropDownList from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlists:

```
<td style="width: 20%;">
    <!-- TASK NAME -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskName" DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Task Name" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateTaskName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gc %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
<td style="width: 20%;">
    <!-- SERVICE -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" DataSourceID="dsPopulateService" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Service" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlService_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateService" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gc %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
```

code-behind on `Page_Load`:

```
strForDropDownList = @" FROM [Db].[dbo].[table1] WHERE [stat] = 'A'";
string pol = " AND ";
if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    pol += " ([tcol] LIKE '%' OR [tcol] IS NULL) AND ";
}
else
{
    pol += " [tcol] = '" + ddlTaskName.SelectedValue.TrimEnd() + "' AND ";
}
if (ddlService.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    pol += " (scol LIKE '%' OR scol IS NULL) AND ";
}
else
{
    pol += " scol = '" + ddlService.SelectedValue.TrimEnd() + "' AND ";
}
strWhere = pol;
dsPopulateTaskName.SelectCommand = @"SELECT DISTINCT [tcol] 'Task Name'" + strForDropDownList + strWhere;
dsPopulateService.SelectCommand = @"SELECT DISTINCT scol 'Service'" + strForDropDownList + strWhere;
```

When the page loads, everything starts with `%` and populates the dropdownlists correctly. If I select an option from the `ddlService` dropdownlist, the `dsPopulateTaskName.SelectCommand` displays the correct query to repopulate the `ddlTaskName` dropdownlist but it doesn't update it.

Please help me resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call `ddlService.DataBind()` and `ddlTaskName.DataBind()` after setting the `SelectCommand` , I mean like below :

```
dsPopulateTaskName.SelectCommand = 
@"SELECT DISTINCT [tcol] 'Task Name'" + strForDropDownList + strWhere;
ddlService.DataBind();

dsPopulateService.SelectCommand = 
@"SELECT DISTINCT scol 'Service'" + strForDropDownList + strWhere;
ddlTaskName.DataBind();
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I have it like this: `ddlTaskName.Items.Clear();ddlTaskName.DataBind();` and it works fine except I lose the `All` which should always exist.

Comment: you don't have to use that line : ddlTaskName.Items.Clear(); it will refresh on databinding

Comment: well,if suppose to update the dropdownlist in SelectIndexChanged please call ddlTaskName.DataBind(); in SelectIndexChanged after setting SelectCommand